# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: It failed with: Connection timed out

Tags: jakarta-ee, wsdl, timeout, client, jax-ws

When try to access a WSDL file from the browser(the URL is http://10.191.245.96/XXXServer/WorkFlowService?wsdl), I am able to access that.But, when I try to access the same WSDL file from java code, I am getting the following exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://10.191.245.96/XXXServer/WorkFlowService?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Connection timed out.
2015-07-02 04:47:26,055 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:162)
2015-07-02 04:47:26,055 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:144)
2015-07-02 04:47:26,055 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:264)
...........
...............
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
2015-07-02 04:47:26,063 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
2015-07-02 04:47:26,063 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
2015-07-02 04:47:26,063 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
2015-07-02 04:47:26,063 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
.............
..............
```

How to resolve the above problem?

Comment: Where is the code doing the connection attempts?

Comment: Are you sure any firewall is not blocking java process to connect?

Comment: Actually, the war file is deployed in a VM, the WSDL exists there only. I mean there shouldn't be any firewall issue since everything exists in the same box. What do you say?

Comment: I am trying to access the above URL from a rest service.